# Could opening something inappropriate on my phone via the company Wi-Fi result in me losing my job?

Tags: technology, inappropriate-content

I was on my personal phone connected to my work network. I have Airwatch installed and they supposedly just monitors email and a VMware browser.

I have a shared folder with friends on Google Drive for a backpacking trip we are planning. One stupid friend uploaded a photo that included nudity, which I didn't open, but the thumbnail loaded while I was connected to my company's WiFi.

I work at a hospital of over 25,000 employees. The feedback I've gotten so far indicates that even if they have the technical abilities to actually see the thumbnail that was loaded, they likely wouldn't even notice. I've never been written up so they have no reason to be monitoring me posting me any special attention. There must be thousands of request per minute and the amount of traffic must be insane where I work, would this ever raise a flag on its own?

Comment: Is the reason they're monitoring your phone because they don't want you seeing naked people or for some other reason? In the financial industry, monitoring is to keep an eye out for inappropriate activity like insider trading. I imagine the hospital is trying to give you access to what you need, but prevent you from sharing that information inappropriately, not prevent you from looking at nudie pictures on your personal device. What does the hospital's policy say about how you can use your personal phone on their network?

Comment: Your connection to Google Drive could be detected by a network administrator, the contents of the download would have been impossible for them to read.

Comment: @GlenPierce, the OP's employer has installed a mobile management app, Airwatch, which can (depending on configuration) allow the network owner to "see" https content.

Answer (score 6):

All you can do is wait and see, so don't let it stress you out. It doesn't fit the bill of what is usually looked for since it's not a porn site (which should be blocked anyway).

I monitor several firewalls which can give me access to what people are looking at, but unless there is an actual reason to start digging I don't look, because the firewalls proactively block most things, really I only see a flag if someone uses a well known proxy or I'm seeing too much usage from someone.

If I was skimming through and saw a bit of nudity I wouldn't care unless it's specifically against policy or was unacceptable in some way such as the age of the nudist. At most I'd give the person a heads up to look at that stuff on their own internet connection, but unless I saw a lot of it and it looked like a trend I wouldn't even bother doing that..

Comment: yeh, this is a fair  answer, all OP can do is wait. and of course not be bothered because it's unlikely to be an issue

Comment: The OP is specifically talking about https traffic from a personal device using the wifi guest access provided by his employer. I don't understand how you could see anything more than the URL's unless you're able to install software on the personal device to make it accept your employer's certificate?

Comment: Oh, I see the OP did put an employer's app on the phone, Airwatch. A cursory google shows that this app can force the device to use employer's cert. That means _all_ https content can be inspected.

Comment: @teego1967 the employer can use a proxy that traps images. They can do it transparently or overtly. Whatever traffic goes through either https or http can be trapped. Use of an app or not doesn't change this. Sophos, watchguard have this capability, even free firewalls like pfsense I think

Comment: @Kilisi, For HTTPS,They would NOT be able to see images or collect any actual content other than url's UNLESS the device was setup by the IT department to accept their certificate authority on behalf of google drive. I think? Isn't that the whole point of TLS?

Comment: @teego1967 If the traffic goes through the firewall it can be trapped, in overt proxy situations accepting the firewalls cert is mandatory... but even transparent can still trap traffic (I think, not something I have tried though, I don't do transparent). Too lazy to look it up for the sake of argument though since it doesn't impact on the answer.

Comment: @Kilisi, the reason I ask is that even among computer proficient folks the nuances of what can and can't be "caught" on a network is very unclear. Most discussions simply end with "the employer owns the network so assume no privacy." It's more complex than that. I think there's a good question in there, but I have not been able to formulate it in a way that would pass the on-topic police of workplace. Even this question is on-hold and downvoted!

Comment: @teego1967 you can capture anything on a network if your IT control clientside, ethically and probably legally there are things you just don't do, but they're still possible. I monitor some systems where I can watch each users desktop at any time and take control if I need to. Theoretically I could record everything they do if I wanted.